# Go to Checkout Complete without checkout payment

Tags: entities, rules, commerce

I created a field **field_cel_ck_scholar**. It's a boolean.
I created this field in a customer profile type. My customer profile type is added in a pane in my checkout.

When this field is equal TRUE, I want by pass the checkout/%/payment's page and to redirect the checkout/%/complete's page.

It's possible ?

I try to use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) like so:

```
{ "rules_by_pass" : {
"LABEL" : "by pass",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_checkout", "commerce_rules_extra" ],
"ON" : { "commerce_rules_extra_process_checkout_page" : [] },
"IF" : [
  { "entity_has_field" : {
      "entity" : [ "site:current-cart-order" ],
      "field" : "field_cel_ck_scholar"
    }
  }
],
"DO" : [
  { "commerce_checkout_complete" : { "commerce_order" : [ "site:current-cart-order" ] } }
]
}
}
```

It doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to create a Rules condition like so:

> if field `field_cel_ck_scholar`=TRUE

whereas you have such field added in your 'customer profile type'.

Looking at the rule you create so far, your Rules condition seems incomplete:

- you already do have the `entity_has_field`, that's OK, and actually one (out of 2) ways to be able to create such condition like "if field `field_cel_ck_scholar`=TRUE".
- your Rules condition seems to be missing the actual *Data comparison* condition, in which you actually specify that "if field `field_cel_ck_scholar`=TRUE".

So try adding such Data Comparison condition, and check if that solves your issue. Not sure if it will be the **only** reason why "It doesn't work", but for sure **a** reason why it cannot work.

PS: refer to my answer to the question about [How to specify a Rules condition related to select list values?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/175988/how-to-specify-a-rules-condition-related-to-select-list-values/176180#176180) for a similar (though not duplicate) question, which includes some more details (and background info) about such `entity_has_field`.

Comment: Thank you for accept! Was it the "only" reason why it didn't work?