# How to unpublish postings according to the value of a field?

Tags: rules

I was able to set rule to unpublished after +30 days. But I would like to tweak my rule to give to my users the possibility to choose between posting for 2 weeks, one month or 3 months.

So, I guess that there would be an "if choice X, than unpublish after Y period of time". Can the field (to choose duration) be a text dropdown?

Can this be done without PHP? If so how?

---

So, I figured out that I can add a condition like this :

```
Parameter: Data to compare: [node:field-time-limit], Data value: 2 weeks
```

But since I have 3 choices for my ads (2 weeks, 1 month, 3 months), does this means that I have to make 3 different rules, one for each time limit?
(it seems to make sense, but I'm not shure).

**Note**: I'm aware of the thread about "[Tutorial 2: Publish content exactly 24 hours after it was created](https://www.drupal.org/node/517674)".

Comment: Yes, its possible through Rules Module (php code not needed) according to your requirment

Comment: You can use rules module for this action,
Refer : https://www.drupal.org/node/517674

Comment: Thanks... So now I know that I dont need PHP (I know nothing about that)!. So I'll keep digging...

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to exist of actually 2 questions, so here are 2 parts of an answer to address each of them (I'm assuming this question is about D7).

## Part 1

Refer to my answer to "[How to specify a Rules condition related to select list values?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/175988/how-to-specify-a-rules-condition-related-to-select-list-values/176180#176180)" for an example Rule (in Rules export format) that allows for specifying a Rules condition related to a specific value selected via a selection list.

With this (and some minor tuning of that sample to fit your field and values), you have an answer to your "***if choice X, than unpublish after Y period of time***".

## Part 2

Refer to my answer to "[Redirect users with specified roles to specified term pages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129749/how-to-redirect-a-user-with-a-specified-role-to-a-specified-term-page/181857#181857)", which shows how you can redirect to ***various URLs*** (depending on some role). It also explains 2 possible approaches for either creating multiple rules (1 for each role) versus just 1 rule (by using the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module).

With this (and some minor tuning of that sample to fit your case here), you have an answer to your "***does this mean that I have to make 3 different rules, one for each time limit***". The actual answer is: either way can work (personally I'd go for just 1 rule, using the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module).

**PS**: So yes this ***can be done without PHP***, it only requires some site building using the Admin UI for Rules.