# Request passphrase at user registration and automatically assign role to user

Tags: 7, users

Is there a module that would allow us to request an optional predefined pass-phrase/password at user registration?

So if the user fills in the pass-phrase he would be registered as a premium user or something, if not he would be set as a simple authenticated user.

By the way, I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: I'm currently using Auto Assign Role and different registration paths which is similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download  [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module
2. Enable Rules and Rules UI
3. In user fields, add a new text field. Name it ex: Catch Phrase (check mark the show on user registration)
4. Add a new rule

   - **React on** (under user) **After saving a new user account**
   - Add Condition: **Data comparison** >> account:field-catch-phrase >> [enter catch phrase]
   - Add Action: (under user) **Add user Role** >> premium role
5. (optional) Download and enable [Field Permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions). With this you can hide the catch phrase field so it doesn't show up when they edit their user account.

Comment: Looks great! I will try it soon and I'll come back with any comments.

Comment: Oeps ....! Looks like "Rules" is the way to go, right? Now what, should I delete my "simultaeniously written answer"?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Sorry, I did say I was taking a pass on this (I deleted comment), but then I couldn't go to bed knowning that Kiamlaluno could close or even delete this Q. If you want to leave your answer, that's fine with me.

Comment: No need for sorry, though "I" wonder what the "rules" (oeps!) are in such scenario like here, where 2 "**pretty similar**" answers where posted more or less at the same time. Would be nice if there would be like a "answer-in-progress"-locking mechanisme (similar to suggested edits), no? Think this is worth asking as a question on meta.SE (and use our both answers as a sample to illustrate it)?

Comment: BTW, not to "argue" about your answer, but as per the current "*I will try it soon*" comment, IMHO the "accepted"-mark seems premature for now, no?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens yes, the accept was premature. I'm fine if you want to use this as an example for meta.SE. I think the rule is whoever answers first, but eh, I am not offended if you leave your answer.

Comment: Ehm.. sorry Pierre. I can't grant you both the answer. I was looking for a quick solution so the acceptance was almost instant. No Sssweat replied slightly first. :( You can have my up-vote of course if this could make up for it..

Comment: @LePhleg : **No need for sorry** either ... but now that you upvoted my answer also, I believe it's OK to leave my answer anyway. If "the community" has other thoughts about that: flag and/or vote it to get it deleted anyway. While waiting for that to ever happen, I *might* further enhance my answer later on. And if it would turn out you don't like the enhanced answer anymore, feel free to then un-upvote it again, ok?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I don't think deleting an answer would be a proper reaction in ANY case. This question is gonna stay here for others to see, so maybe your approach fit them better or make the solution more clear to them. Please feel free to edit or enhance it, my upvote is permanent for your contribution. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to implement such feature, as further detailed  below.

**Step 1**: Add a field to the registration form, which wil be used to have a user enter your passphrase. Even though you can use any "machine name" for that field, let's assume you call it "`field_optionlist`"

**Step 2**: Use a variation of the Rule included in my answer to "[How to specify a Rules condition related to select list values?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/175988/how-to-specify-a-rules-condition-related-to-select-list-values/176180#176180)". Here is what you should tune in that rule:

- Replace the **Rules event** to something like "After a new user submits a registration request"
- Replace the "Value C" in the **Rules condition** to the value of your passphrase
- For debugging reasons, start with a Drupal message to be shown (imilar to the rule mentioned above. After the message shows up as you want it to show, replace the Rules Action with something like "Assign role to user".